# How to compute cross entropy loss for binary classification in Pytorch ？

Tags: pytorch

For binary classification, my output and label is like this

```
output = [0.7, 0.3, 0.1, 0.9 ... ]
label = [1, 0, 0, 1 ... ]
```

where the output is the probability for `precited label = 1`

And I want a cross entropy like this:

```
def cross_entropy(output, label):
    return sum(-label * log(output) - (1 - label) * log(1 - output))
```

However, this gives me a NaN error because that in `log(output)` the `output` might be zero.

I know there is `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss` however it does not apply for my data format here.

Comment: How about using `torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy`.

Comment: Or what about `torch.nn.BCELoss`? BCE refers to "Binary Cross Entropy".

Comment: @Leonard2 why don't you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
def my_binary_cross_entrophy(output,label):
    label = label.float()
    #print(label)
    loss = 0
    for i in range(len(label)):
        loss += -(label[i]*math.log(output[i])+(1-label[i])*math.log(1-output[i]))
        #print(loss)
    return loss/len(label)

label1 = torch.randint(0,2,(3,)).float()
output = torch.rand(3)
my_binary_cross_entrophy(output,label1)
```

The value it returned is the same as F.binary_cross_entropy value.

```
F.binary_cross_entropy(output,label1)
```

Comment: little bit explanation is needed to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

As [Leonard2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5250010/leonard2) mentioned in a comment to the question, [`torch.nn.BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bceloss) (meaning "Binary Cross Entropy Loss" seems to be exactly what was asked for.